# Laravel Domain specific configurations

Tags: php, subdomain, laravel-5, appdomain

I have a single app in Laravel and I don't want install it separately for each client. So I need to detect the client from a sub domain and load their configurations according to that.

How do I do that from Laravel 5.2? Appreciate your experienced answers. Is my approach is good or should it better install separately?

Actually I need to detect the client before he logged in. So I can load a different login view for each client with logos etc.

Comment: Tried searching for some `multi-tenant` packages for `Laravel`?

Answer (score 2):

It's good approach to keep all client sensitive configs in `.env` files and use [DotEnv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) as it [does](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration)  Laravel

For example

#### client1 `.env`

```
CLIENT_NAME=Nick  
CLIENT_EMAIL=nick@domain.com
```

### client2 `.env`

```
CLIENT_NAME=Tom  
CLIENT_EMAIL=tom@domain.com
```

Then in your `config/app.php` for example

```
'client_name' => env('CLIENT_NAME', 'Here you can set default value'),

'client_email' => env('CLIENT_EMAIL', 'Here you can set default value'),
```

Now you can access them something like

```
$clientName = config('app.client_name');

$clientEmail = config('app.client_email');
```

Comment: So can I use separate .env files for each subdomain somewhere?

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what do you try to achieve?

Comment: Hi @huuk, Actually I need to detect the client before he logged in. So I can load a different login view for each client with logos etc.

Comment: I am going to detect it from a the subdomain.

Comment: May be [Sub-Domain Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) will be fit your needs